# How to publish messages to a virtual topic in AMQP

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, virtual-topic

I published messages to a topic in ActiveMQ using AMQP with the SenderLink API. I used the node address pointing to `topic://topicname`.

For VirtualTopic I went through [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations). Changing the configuration as noted and renaming the topic name to `VirtualTopic.TopicName` is not publishing the messages on to queue.

Should the node address be different? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue must exist *before* the message is produced.